# How to embed RMarkdown (in html format) on Wordpress

Tags: r, wordpress, r-markdown

I create reports in `RMarkdown` and would like to upload them to a Wordpress website. I found several tutorials using `RWordPress` to directly post/edit R code to Wordpress.

https://yihui.org/knitr/demo/wordpress/

Since I only want to post my static content once, it would be sufficient for me to do it manually. I'm looking for an easier option to put the markdown-html file on my wordpress site. I so far just copied the html-code and posted it manually as html-element on wordpress. The result looks almost ok, but there are some errors and it hurts my overall layout and menu.

I would like to obtain something like:

http://3.14a.ch/archives/2015/03/08/how-to-publish-with-r-markdown-in-wordpress/

What is the best practice to put RMarkdown (as a kind of blog entry) on a wordpress homepage (and  header, footer, navigation, etc.)?

Comment: Would it be satisfactory for you to embed a PDF instead of HTML?

Comment: Not really, since layout (pagebreak) is not very flexible.